# How do I get Dictionary from json and store in the another Dictionary

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nsdictionary

I am trying to develop a `UIPickerView` which will have only value array in it.So i will have one Dictionary(venue) to store both key and value from json and one Array(venueValue) that will only store value.By using venueValue i can show the results in UIPickerView.But,I want key of the value that the user select from picker.Unfortunately,I am think off how to get Dictionary(key:value) and Array(key) from my json.Any Help?

```
var venue = [String:String]()
var venueValue = [String]()

var selectedValue : String? // to show in text box after picker selected and to get key of selected value from venue

func populateVenues(completion : (error: NSError?,value : [String]?,dict : [String:String]) -> Void){
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://localhost:8080/xxx/xxx/xxx")!)
    var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    var err: NSError?

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        println("Auction : Request Completed")

        var err: NSError?

        if error == nil{
            var venues = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as! NSDictionary

            for (k, v) in venues {

                if let value = v as? [String] {
                    println(value)
                    // Acutally value should start from "All Venue".I wonder why it start at "ZeroCentral",Please check my output.
                    self.venueValue.append(value[0])
                }
            }
            //I still dont get the dictionary yet.how to change NSDictionary to Dictionary
            // What i want is to store value in venueValue and to store both key and value in venue because when the picker can only store array.So i gonna get the selected value from picker and get the key of selected value from dictionary(venue)

            completion(error: nil,value: venueValue,dict:venues)
        }
        else{
            println(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        if(err != nil) {
            // If there is an error parsing JSON, print it to the console
            println("JSON Error \(err!.localizedDescription)")
        }

    })

    task.resume()
}
```

Here is my venues output.

```
{
0 =     (
    "All Venues"
);
"100_152" =     (
    "ORIX Fukuoka"
);
"101_164" =     (
    "ORIX IP Stock"
);
"102_131" =     (
    "ORIX Kobe"
);
"103_135" =     (
    "ORIX Nagoya"
);
"104_132" =     (
    "ORIX Sendai"
);
"105_54" =     (
    "SAA Hamamatsu"
);
"106_29" =     (
    "SAA Sapporo"
);
"107_184" =     (
    Sakura
);
}
```

And the venueValue that i try to output was not sorted like venue output

```
[ORIX Nagoya]
[ORIX IP Stock]
[ORIX Kobe]
[All Venues]
[ORIX Fukuoka]
…...
```

Why it was not like the old one?If i want to start from "All Venues",How to do that?Any Help?Please I am so close to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Create two arrays like this.

```
var venueId = [String]()
var venueValue = [String]()

var selectedValue : String?

func populateVenues(completion : (error: NSError?,results : [String]?,keys : [String]) -> Void){
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://localhost:8080/xxx/xxx/xxx")!)
    var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    var err: NSError?

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        println("Auction : Request Completed")

        var err: NSError?

        if error == nil{
            var venues = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as! [String: AnyObject]

            for (k, v) in venues {

                println("key is : \(k).Value is : \(v)")
                // This is where I start having trouble.
                // I want to append k to venueId and v to venueValue
                venueId.append(k)
                if let value = v as? Array[String] {
                   venueValue.append(value[0])
                }
            }

            completion(error: nil,results: self.venueId,keys:self.venueValue!)
        }
        else{
            println(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        if(err != nil) {
            // If there is an error parsing JSON, print it to the console
            println("JSON Error \(err!.localizedDescription)")
        }

    })

    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: I cant.It keep showing me these.http://puu.sh/i13Kw/eed348c2a6.png.When i fix that,it show "Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayM' (0x10728a448) to 'NSString' (0x10795c8e0)." in output

Comment: ,I am sorry that it was my work finish time,so i have to back to home.I still having error when i type as  u told,http://puu.sh/i1VVU/11347351d3.png.Thanks for your help.Not solve yet .:(

Comment: I got the venueValue now.But i cant store venues(NSDictionary) to venue[String:String]().And also my venueValue output is not sorted like venue output.Please Help

Answer (score 0):

From your venues output it looks like the value in each dictionary is an array with 1 element in it.

You need to extract that single item.

Actually you'll need to cast the dictionary value to type [String] and then extract the first element.

It looks like @Aimit89 set up his code to deal with the data you're getting.

Comment: I got the venueValue now.But i cant store venues(NSDictionary) to venue[String:String]().And also my venueValue output is not sorted like venue output.Please Help.I am so close to my answer.